# x-blackberry-focusable does not work

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I create a simple page and try it on BlackBerry device but the highlight does not work, can somebody help me to tell what is wrong with my codes here?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style>
        .list {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #CCC;
            border-width: 1px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 2px;
        }

        .list:hover {
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="list" x-blackberry-initialFocus="true" x-blackberry-focusable="true">List 1</div>
        <div class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true">List 2</div>
        <div class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true">List 3</div>
        <div class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true">List 4</div>
        <div class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true">List 5</div>
        <div class="list" x-blackberry-focusable="true">List 6</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file looks correct.  It could be that you have not enabled focus mode navigation from your config.xml file. Ensure that you have the **<rim:navigation mode="focus" />** element set in config.xml, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" 
    version="1.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>Focus demo</name>

    <content src="index.htm" />
    <feature id="blackberry.system" />
    <rim:navigation mode="focus" />

</widget>
```